# PHP - Drop down as variable not being passed

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a variable from a drop down list. The drop down list is fully populated using a mysql query, and demonstrates the correct information I'd be expecting. I have found an example online (the bottom one) which does exactly what I want it to, but my example (the top one) is not. I presume this is something to do with the fact that it is populated by database info rather than plain text, but I can't work out precisely what is wrong.

This is what populates the table and is working fine.

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT athleteforename, athletesurname FROM athletes WHERE userID='$userID'"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
$options=""; 
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$forename=$row["athleteforename"]; 
$surname=$row["athletesurname"];         
$options.="<option value='$id'>" . $forename . ' ' . $surname . '</option>';
}
?>
```

This one echos "name is set to" but then no value is given. It is full of the correct names, though.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select NAME="name" onchange="this.form.submit();"> 
<?=$options?>
</select>
</form>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {echo 'name is now set to ' . $_POST['$name'];} 
?>
```

This one works exactly as I want the top one to.

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
<select name="var" onchange="this.form.submit();"> 
<option value="1">var 1</option> 
<option value="2">var 2</option> 
<option value="3">var 3</option> 
<option value="4">var 4</option> 
<option value="5">var 5</option> 
</select> 
</form> 

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['var'])) {echo 'var is now set to ' . $_POST['var'];} 
?>
```

Comment: To debug, try putting some print statement for the values of forename and surname just to validate that results are being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it is this line:

`$options.="<option value='$id'>" . $forename . ' ' . $surname . '</option>';`

Where is `$id` coming from? Seems to be uninitialized.

You could also have a look at the output HTML generated by your script to find the difference to the working example you found.

Another thing:

Your code will produce HTML like (if you had `$id=3`): `<option value='3'>`. That's no so nice. ;) Browsers will probably accept it, but "good" HTML should use `"`s. So if you have the `$id` initialized propery, the line above should rather look like this:

`$options.='<option value="$id">' . $forename . ' ' . $surname . '</option>';`

**Edit:**

Konstantinos Botonakis found another issue: `$_POST['$name'];` should be `$_POST['name'];` IMHO.

Comment: I am not sure where $id comes from. The curse of using other examples of code without fully understanding them, I suppose. I will look into why that exists. Thank you.

I am not sure how to look at the output html - is this viewing the source code of the php page in the browser?

Comment: Well, I am going to mark yours as the answer as changing to $_POST['name']; and changing <option value='$id'> to just <option> has made this code work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you have:

```
$_POST['$name'];
```

you should change it:

```
$_POST[$name];
```

Comment: Errm... `$_POST['name'];`, isn't it? ;)

Comment: Thank you - changing it to $_POST['name'] was part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring the variable right  . 
$varaible =['value'] ;
value is generally the dropdown value . 
for eg: 
var 1
so, when you echo $variable 
it will show the value var 1 .

Use this and hope it solves the problem .

Comment: Thank you for your help.